# File splitter in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a file splitter/joiner in C++ and I have trouble with my split function. I used an MP4 file for a quick test and the result was: every other parts are OK but the last part always doesn't work. I don't understand this. Can anyone please explain it to me? Here is my split function:

```
void split_F(const char* file_name, int number_of_part)
{
    FILE *fp_read = fopen(file_name, "rb");

    //calculate file size
    int file_size;
    fseek(fp_read, 0L, SEEK_END);
    file_size = ftell(fp_read);
    rewind(fp_read); //reset file pointer

    //calculate number of parts
    //int number_of_part = (int)ceil((double)file_size / size_of_part);
    long size_of_part;
    size_of_part = (int)floor((double)file_size / number_of_part);
    cout << "Total files after split: " << number_of_part << endl
        << "...Processing..." << endl;

    //main process
    char name[255] = "";
    for (int count = 1; count <= number_of_part; count++) 
    {
        sprintf(name, "%s.part_%03d", file_name, count);
        FILE *fp_write = fopen(name, "wb");

        //create buffer
        char *buffer = new char[size_of_part];
        memset(buffer, NULL, size_of_part); //reset buffer

        fread(buffer, size_of_part, 1, fp_read);
        fwrite(buffer, size_of_part, 1, fp_write);
        fseek(fp_read, count*size_of_part, SEEK_SET);

        cout << "> File: " << name << " done babe!" << endl;

        delete[] buffer;
        fclose(fp_write);
    }
        fclose(fp_read);
}
```

Comment: That's not C, that's C++.

Comment: oops sorry, my university teach both so I'm pretty confused

Comment: explain "doesn't work"

Comment: technically, this will not compile in C, because of the operator new[]

Comment: Just a couple of hints: you don't need to create the buffer separately for each part and you don't need to empty it since you're reading into it. Also even though it compiles, don't use NULL in memset. You're setting the values to zero, so use a zero. NULL is a pointer, not a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last part will be potentially smaller or larger than size_of_part, as the original file size is not a multiple of it.

You need to adapt the size of the last part automatically.

For instance, if you have a file size of 1000 bytes, and 7 parts.
Your computed file size will be 142. 7*142 = 994, you are missing the last 6 bytes. Is this your problem?

The fseek is not required, why are you using it? You just need to read the input file sequentially

```
void split_F(const char* file_name, int number_of_part)
{
    FILE *fp_read = fopen(file_name, "rb");

    //calculate file size
    int file_size;
    fseek(fp_read, 0L, SEEK_END);
    file_size = ftell(fp_read);
    rewind(fp_read); //reset file pointer

    //calculate number of parts
    long size_of_part;
    size_of_part = (int)ceil((double)file_size / number_of_part);
    cout << "Total files after split: " << number_of_part << endl
        << "...Processing..." << endl;

    //main process
    char name[255] = "";
    int bytesRemaining = file_size;

    //create buffer, we reuse it for each part
    char *buffer = new char[size_of_part];

    //No need to reset buffer
    //memset(buffer, NULL, partSize);


    for (int count = 1; count <= number_of_part; count++) 
    {
        sprintf(name, "%s.part_%03d", file_name, count);
        FILE *fp_write = fopen(name, "wb");

        int partSize;
        if(bytesRemaining > size_of_part)
        {
            partSize = size_of_part;
        }
        else
        {
            partSize = bytesRemaining;
        }

        fread(buffer, partSize, 1, fp_read);
        fwrite(buffer, partSize, 1, fp_write);

        cout << "> File: " << name << " done babe!" << endl;

        fclose(fp_write);
    }
    fclose(fp_read);
    delete[] buffer;
}
```

Comment: do you mean that the last part has to written separately? If so then what is the size of the last part ? I guess it's
long remaining_size = file_size - (number_of_part - 1)*size_of_part;
please correct me if am wrong

Comment: No, see my updated code. The number of bytes written will be variable, and equal to the minimum of total remaining bytes and size_of_part

Comment: Please note that I use "ceil" instead of "floor" for avoiding missing some bytes in the last part

Comment: Your C is good. Your logic is not! If you miss some bytes in your count, you will do the same error in any language

Comment: @GiaPhatHa : do you need any more help with this question? Remember : you can accept this answer if it was the correct solution. Read more about accepting answers here : http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: can I ask you one more thing :D

Comment: I solved that problem I was about to ask you somehow :D By the way, thank you again for your help Mr.galinette @galinette

Answer (score 0):

You are calculating `size_of_part` as a rounded quotient of file size and the requested number of parts. You then proceed to read the file in chunks of that exact size. This will fail unless the file size is a multiple of `number_of_parts`. You need to fix your code to allow the last part to be smaller than `size_of_part`.

Comment: This is not correct; since he used `floor` the last part will be larger than `size_of_part`

Comment: @galinette Good point, although the OP edited his answer in the meantime. However, a correctly written splitter never allows a chunk to be **larger** than the prescribed chunk size (because then it wouldn't fit on a fixed-size media, for example), so the text in the answer should apply.

Answer (score 0):

Your file may not divide into N parts of equal lengths (suppose the file is 7 bytes long and you divide it into 3 parts...?)

```
long remaining_size = file_size;
long size_of_part;
size_of_part = (file_size + number_of_part - 1) / number_of_part;
```

This makes the part length rounded up, so possibly the last part will be shorter than all preceding parts.

```
//create buffer
char *buffer = new char[size_of_part];

//main process
char name[255] = "";
for (int count = 1; count <= number_of_part; count++) 
{
    sprintf(name, "%s.part_%03d", file_name, count);
    FILE *fp_write = fopen(name, "wb");

    long this_part_size =
        remaining_size < size_of_part ? remaining_size : size_of_part;

    fread(buffer, this_part_size, 1, fp_read);
    fwrite(buffer, this_part_size, 1, fp_write);

    cout << "> File: " << name << " done babe!" << endl;

    fclose(fp_write);

    remaining_size -= this_part_size;
}
delete[] buffer;
```